# Java FileInputStream/Scanner trouble with Android

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to load some resources in Java for Android. Those resources are simple text files and I need to read things in them. I have quite a bit of experience with reading and writing to such files, but right now something is breaking it.

This is the code I'm using.

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file:///android_asset/Peacefulpack.mod");
```

So when I run this it should search for the `Peacefulpack.mod` in this directory: `file:///android_asset/Peacefulpack.mod`

However, when I take a look at the console logs it tells me that Java is looking for this directory: `file:///android_asset/Peacefulpack.mod`

This gives me a `FileNotFoundException`. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: is there a reason you're specifying the path like that? I mean, you could probably obtain an InputStream or even file handle with `getResources` or `getAssets` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to load some resources in Java for Android.

Since you want work with data stored in Android pre-defined directory, Android offers methods directly designated for your goal.

At first look at [`AssetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) that offers following method:

- [public final InputStream open (String fileName)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29)

that is most likely what you are looking for. Method returns `InputStream` of file stored in assets folder.

Basic usage:

```
AssetManager am = this.getAssets(); // or YourActivity.this.getAssets()
   try { // generally Context
      InputStream is = am.open("yourFile.suffix");
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
      Log.w("IOException", e.getMessage());
   }
```

It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

use this method public final InputStream open (String fileName) in AssetManager

see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open(java.lang.String)